# Manipulate only the numerical values of a bi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having an array or array of this form:

```
anArray = [
    ["name0", 1, 3, 4, "name1"],
    ["name2", 5, 5, 12, 1],
];
```

I want to perform some operations only on numerical values inside the array, for example add them by 2.

My solution which doesn't work:

```
anArray.forEach((subAr) => {
    subAr.filter(s => (typeof s) === 'number').map(a => a + 2);
});
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`; you're throwing away the result of your `subAr` map...

Comment: Do you want to filter and make separate array too?

Comment: I want to modify the original array

Comment: @Archer it doesn't work. Probably there are more things to change

Comment: @Archer `anArray.map(subArr => subArr.map(a => typeof a === 'number' ? a + 2 : a))` returns an array with each numeric value incremented by 2. I apparently assumed too much, my apologies.

Comment: @HereticMonkey There was more wrong with it, but you were right, *if* you don't want to assign the result to the array variable.

Comment: @Archer to be fair, it *is* a comment, not an answer :P.

Comment: It was leading them down an incorrect route to the answer - wasn't a criticism, as you can see from my last comment :)

Comment: Anyway, OP your code removes everything that isn't a number (when it's fixed).  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mutate the array, just use a regular for loop:

```
for(const subArray of anArray) {
  for(const [index, entry] of subArray.entries()) {
     if(typeof entry === "number") {
       subArray[index] = entry + 2;
     }
   }
}
```

Or if you prefer unreadable code, here you go:

```
anArray = anArray.map(subArray => subArray.map(entry => typeof entry === "number" ? entry + 2 : entry));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't alter numbers like that, you'll have to refernce them using the sub array (using `forEach` for examaple):

```
anArray.forEach(subAr => 
    subAr.forEach((n, i) => subAr[i] = typeof n == "number"? n + 2: n)
);
```

```js
let anArray = [
    ["name0", 1, 3, 4, "name1"],
    ["name2", 5, 5, 12, 1],
];  

anArray.forEach(subAr => 
    subAr.forEach((n, i) => subAr[i] = typeof n == "number"? n + 2: n)
);

console.log(anArray);
```

Or replace the whole sub array using `map`:

```
anArray = anArray.map(subAr => 
    subAr.map(n => typeof n == "number"? n + 2: n)
);
```

```js
let anArray = [
    ["name0", 1, 3, 4, "name1"],
    ["name2", 5, 5, 12, 1],
];  

anArray = anArray.map(subAr => 
    subAr.map(n => typeof n == "number"? n + 2: n)
);

console.log(anArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the result of the forEach loop. This code should do the job :

```js
anArray = [
        ["name0", 1, 3, 4, "name1"],
        ["name2", 5, 5, 12, 1],
];  
anArray = anArray.map(subArray => subArray.map(el => (typeof el) ==="number" ? el + 2 : el ))

console.log(anArray);
```